# ArcGIS 10.1 License issue on Mac Parallels 9

Tags: macos, arcgis, parallels

I've been using ArcGIS 10.1 on my MacBook Pro (2011 model) via Boot Camp for a few months. A few days ago, I just installed Parallels 9 in order to use ArcGIS and my Mac programs at the same time and I've run into an issue with the license needing to be repaired. When I try to open ArcMap via Parallels, I get an error message saying something to the effect of "the license is in need of repair". When I installed Parallels 9, I chose to import my Boot Camp so I didn't have to reinstall anything. My guess is that ArcGIS thinks Parallels is a different computer and that's why the license is failing? Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I can get a hold of another ArcGIS license so if it's a matter of using another license, I should be ok. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest asking this on gis.stackexchange.com rather than here (Stack Overflow is more for specifically programming related questions).  Additionally, contact ESRI or your reseller directly for support.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use ArcGIS on Bootcamp and VM with the same license key (single use license! - concurrenct use license with separat license server of course no problem). The license key is generated with some internal ids of your computer (eg ethernet MAC and other - you can match the ethernet MAC id in Parallels but thats not enough). You have to chose where you want to work with ArcGIS: bootcamp or VM (before licensing). Thats really annoying...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Extremely annoying since it is without a doubt impossible to run both your BootCamp and VM versions at the same time. I never resolved it with traditional fixer.

If you are a student (hopefully you are) usually the person/department in charge of license distribution understand the need for both (rasters can be very sluggish on the VM side, but not always) when you are really putting the machine to the test.

SO, that is how i ultimately "solved" the issue. However, I believe the route issue to be the MAC address authentication, as I am experiencing the same problem in ArcGIS 10.2 when I tried to copy my VM from my MBP optical drive to my MBP sad - none of my tools are working.

When I first loaded the copied VM (by opening the VM file directly, not through Parallels) I was prompted if I wanted to use the same "......" (can't remember the actual term, but something along the lines of MAC id, or network address, etc.). Unfortunately I said no make a new one - WRONG ANSWER.

I'm trying to get it sorted now - just saved VM file, completely wiped Parallels, reboot, reinstall; and now I'm on the message boards trying to get this install right) [helpful ideal VM settings for ArcGIS specifically: http://maps.uky.edu/support/docs/BP_ArcGIS_on_Macv5.pdf  ).

All that being said the first time I had this issue (month of nightmares, and late GIS homework) I had imported my VM from Bootcamp, which seems logical, but at that time (Parallels 8 and ArcGIS 10) it was still a license error I was receiving, but for some unremembered reason I was convinced it was because the VM calls its hard drive the "C" drive which it clearly is not - parallels merely translates this virtual C drive between the 2 OSs and their respective boot drives.

( I have not tried this next part yet) it might be worth trying to install your VM on the Mac side and then use the Windows or Parallels Migration Tool to create a Win migration file and then go to your BootCamp side (**IMPORTANT - DEACTIVATE YOUR ESRI LICENSE BEFORE UNINSTALLING ARCGIS** - if you don't do then you'll be mired in the "this license has reached its maximum allowable installations" or whatever they say).

If your Bootcamp side still has your ArcGIS, deactivate, then uninstall that version. Then try to import your migration file, but I've lost some of my Windows skills since switching to Mac, so I would do some research on that part. In theory since, your VM version was pointing to (for all intents and purposes) your "C" drive on the Mac side, hopefully the BootCamp install won't get as tripped up by the double installs as the VM did. 
Just a thought, I realize as I finish this that you posted in October, so likely you've moved on, but if any of what I said is wrong, or if you found the best way to have it all, I would really appreciate your response.

Comment: Could you format your post, this is simply horrible.